# How to get the file upload button to show in the EditMe extension

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I'm using the ExtEditMe extension in my project with the following configuration:

```
$this->widget('ext.editMe.widgets.ExtEditMe',
    array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'attribute'=>'Text',
        'ckeConfig'=>array('enableTabKeyTools'=>true,'enterMode'=>2),
        'height'=>'500',
        'width'=>'100%',
        'filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'=>'/protected/extensions/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files',
        'filebrowserImageUploadUrl'=>'/protected/extensions/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files',
        'filebrowserBrowseUrl'=>'/protected/extensions/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files',
        'filebrowserUploadUrl'=>'/protected/extensions/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files'
    )
);
```

For some reason the file upload button isn't showing in the tool bar.  Is there something else I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

Questions too much for a comment.  Could you check the following:

- Check the permissions for the assets folder. Need to be writable by your
  httpd (example apache:apache or apache:www-data)
- EditMe should be inside the protected/extensions/ folder
- Change your widget call to:
  $this->widget('application.extensions.editme.widgets.ExtEditMe',
  (used full path)
- Check if kcfinder/config.php says:   'disabled' => false,

Also, there may be a need to put kcfinder in the root of the webapp. See this example with [CKeditor](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/432/ckeditor-integration-includes-steps-for-file-uploads-step-by-step/).

Comment: All these check out and I changed the call to 'application.extensions.editme.widgets.ExtEditMe' but I'm still not seeing the file upload button.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

The following comes from the [CKEDITOR docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_dialog_add_file_browser):

> This button will be hidden by default (hidden:true). The filebrowser plugin looks for all elements with the filebrowser attribute and unhides them if appropriate configuration setting is available ([filebrowserBrowseUrl/filebrowserUploadUrl](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload-section-1)).

Which could mean your config settings for the filebrowser plugin are not correct. You should try the following:

- KCFinder (your filebrowser plugin) is not a yii extension as far as I know, so move the `kcfinder` folder to the root folder (or any other folder outside of the protected folder).
- Change the paths to the KCFinder files. I recommend using yii's `Yii::app()->baseUrl` to make sure you're getting the correct paths:

  ```
  'filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files',
  'filebrowserImageUploadUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files',
  'filebrowserBrowseUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files',
  'filebrowserUploadUrl'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files'
  ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good suggestions but alas, they didn't make the file upload button show up. :(

Comment: Check out [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/28561-integrating-yii-ckeditor-and-kcfinder/) - seems like something to try

Answer (score 1):

```
'filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'=>'/protected/extensions/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files',
'filebrowserImageUploadUrl'=>'/protected/extensions/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files',
'filebrowserBrowseUrl'=>'/protected/extensions/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files',
'filebrowserUploadUrl'=>'/protected/extensions/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files'
```

These URLs will be passed to the Javascript initiator of the extension, and they will be requested from there, so you can copy them and try requesting them from the browser to see if they are working (I'm almost sure they won't work).

One way you can work this out, is by creating a controller and includes these PHP files there, then make these URLs refer to the controller you created. Hope it helps.

Comment: You're right that `/protected/extensions/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files` doesn't work but `/protected/extensions/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files` does.  If thats the case, why does the image upload button show up and work?

Comment: Another thing I just noticed is if I comment ALL of those lines out, the Image and Flash upload buttons still appear.  Why?

Comment: Sorry I don't have this extension locally to try, but I think it makes sense, as the images and the flash resources can be requested fine, but the upload buttons are being requested from `/protected/extensions/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files` using GET, so it's not working, have you tried the controller approach.